# Problem with execution of cron Magento 2.4.3 - Cron execute twice!

Tags: magento2, cron, crontab

I have problems running cron on Magento 2.4.3

My crontab is configured in this way:

```
#~ MAGENTO START ebd31839b0ed05bdb6ca8efa81d9bd8cc8bb1f90bbec3b545ed65991c8a7d49a
*/5 * * * * /usr/bin/php /home/www/maisondudesign.it/htdocs/bin/magento cron:run 2>&1 | grep -v "Ran jobs by schedule" >> /home/www/maisondudesign.it/htdocs/var/log/cron/magento.cron.log
#~ MAGENTO END ebd31839b0ed05bdb6ca8efa81d9bd8cc8bb1f90bbec3b545ed65991c8a7d49a
```

My Magento configuration is:

```
Generate Schedules Every - 5
Schedule Ahead for - 20
Missed if Not Run Within - 60
History Cleanup Every - 60
Success History Lifetime - 60
Failure History Lifetime - 600
Use Separate Process - No
```

My cronjob is configurated like this:

```
<group id="default">
        <job instance="Homemania\CustomFunction\Cron\LoadFunction" method="execute" name="import_wisigo_apply_all">
            <schedule>*/10 * * * *</schedule>
        </job>
    </group>
```

After 10 minutes, the job fails and a new job starts

The initial job however is still continuing its execution and therefore I find myself with two jobs that are running

I put logs and saw that the initial job is continuing to run

[image]

How can I make magento not mark my job as failed and then keep it running without starting another?

Thanks,
Andrea

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you should change cron execution to run on every minute `* * * * *`. Magento internal cron scheduler is taking responsibility of executing jobs at right moment and you can tweak them in the Magento dashboard.

Are you sure that this job is still running? Maybe dashboard displays empty value in the Finito alle column, because it failed.

I'd check system tasks status with `htop` first, and also determine whether cron is not killed by PHP due to memory exhaustion or too long script execution.